empty $_POST array
I am shown that my $_POST array is empty, despite of the fact that everything else seems to work fine. Necessary limitations for post_max_size uploading in php.ini have already been set, enctype="multipart/form-data" have been set. However, $_POST array is still empty.
screen from the debugging process
Here is the form that I submit.
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Word</th>
            <th>Meaning</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="word" placeholder="Enter word"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="meaning" placeholder="Enter meaning"></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="image"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>


I have read all the available material on that topic and followed all advised steps. However, problem stays the same.

Can you put print_r($_POST); and print_r($_FILES); on top of your index.php and show us what you have there AFTER submit?

@mitkosoft you mean like that? <?php
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
require 'img.php';
require 'pass.php';
echo $_POST['word'];
var_dump($_POST);
echo nl2br("script started\n");
echo "end";
$image = new img();
$image -> uploadImage();

At a guess, some sort of redirect has occurred, turning the request into a GET, maybe. Use your browser's Developer Tools (in the Network tool) to see what is happening

@DamirKoblev, Put var_dump($_POST); at the very beginning of the file (right after the <?php). If it's non-empty, one of the included files could override the $_POST. Otherwise, I guess there might be an issue with the web server configuration (Nginx, Apache etc.). Also, ensure that the index.php in the action  points to the correct file. Consider using a more specific URL for debugging (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php)
